# Node.Js/Electron using mssql module to insert form data into a table

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js

I'll preface this with a I am noob.

I am trying to insert data into my MSSQL table using javascript. I am using [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait) module, which I successfully used to read data, so I know it works, or at least the connection works enough for me to read it.

So basically I have a form with 2 inputs first and last name, and then you click submit and it will add those names to the form. I can't seem to get this to happen. I feel I am missing some part of the documentation, but I can't youtube or find an answer here yet.

The offending code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Add New User</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Add New User</h1>
<div class="container">
    <form id="newUser">
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="newUsrFirstName"></input>
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="newUsrLastName"></input>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
<script>Here is my javascript</script>
```

Then the offending javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const electron = require('electron');
    const mssql = require('mssql');
    //Gather the data
    const form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);

    function submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const firstName = document.querySelector('#newUsrFirstName').value;
        const lastName = document.querySelector('#newUsrLastName').value;
        //console.log(firstName, lastName);
        //Attempt to send to Server MSSQL
        //Database Details not secure but eh, internal app
        const config = {
            user: 'username',
            password: 'password',
            server: 'thedevilswork\\SQLExpress',
            database: 'nirvana',
        };
        var addConn = (async function() {
            try {
                let pool = await sql.connect(config);
                let results = await pool.request()
                return await pool.request().query('insert into dbo.nirvana (FirstName, LastName, AmountDuePrevious, AmountDueCurrent) values (lastName , firstName , 0, 0);');
                //.query('insert into dbo.nirvana (FirstName, LastName, AmountDuePrevious, AmountDueCurrent) values ('+lastName+' , '+firstName+' , 0, 0);');
                console.log(results);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Be kind I am learning still so I apologise if this is obvious.

Comment: The code executes without an error but you don't see you row? or you see an error on console?

Comment: No I see no error, which confuses me, I also see no new row in my database. I feel a little lost without error messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont know if its too late. But the problem is here:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
........^.........v.........................
let pool = await sql.connect(config);
```

Change it to:

```
let pool = await mssql.connect(config);
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time, I do appreciate it. I tested your solution and I'm a dickhead.

Comment: We all make mistakes :D

Answer (score 1):

OK I seem to have convinced it to work. I needed to keep adding `const = require ('mssql');` a bunch which I don't fully comprehend why. I will post the full bottom section to my code in the hope that this question comes up for someone else in the future.

Here is the revised code, I also spent a bunch of time figuring out the sql query so that it would accept my variables properly. This was trail and error and very messy so I do not recommend my particular method to arrive at the result.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

        const electron = require('electron');
        const mssql = require('mssql');

        //Gather the data
        const form = document.querySelector('form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
        function submitForm(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            const firstName = document.querySelector('#newUsrFirstName').value;
            const lastName = document.querySelector('#newUsrLastName').value;
            //console.log(firstName, lastName);

            //Attempt to send to Server MSSQL
            //Database Details not secure but eh, internal app
            const config = {
                user: 'username',
                password: 'password',
                server: 'devilsworkstation\\SQLExpress',
                database: 'nirvana',
            };

            var addConn = (async function () {
                try {

                    const sql = require('mssql')
                    let pool = await sql.connect(config);
                    let results = await pool.request()
                    return await pool.request()
                        .query('insert into dbo.nirvana (FirstName, LastName, AmountDuePrevious, AmountDueCurrent) values (' + "'" + firstName + "'" + ',' + "'" + lastName + "'" + ', 0, 0);');
                    //.query('insert into dbo.nirvana (FirstName, LastName, AmountDuePrevious, AmountDueCurrent) values ('+lastName+' , '+firstName+' , 0, 0);');
                    console.log(results);
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

 addConn();
        }






    </script>
```